# Strange behavior on animated icon with Snap.svg

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to animate a search icon with Snap.svg. You can see that [here on my Codepen](http://codepen.io/Hugo8705/pen/MagpQb), the search icon.

I use transform scale to have my icon "bouncing" on each click : `loupe.animate({transform: 's1.2s.8'},300,mina.easeout);`

The animation runs well except on first click, where it just scales down, then on the second click the effect is ok.

Same behavior with the refresh icon (at the bottom of the Pen), the rotation animation turn in the wrong sense on first click althought I reset transform before animate.

I guess maybe my icons aren't scaled and rotate on good position before first click but I can't find where I could check/set that.

Thank you very much for your help !

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute values by using capital letters:

```
loupe.animate({transform: 'S1.2S.8'},300,mina.easeout);
```

Comment: I've tried it but I still get the animation on first click with a wrong behavior. Then on others clicks, the animation runs well.

Comment: Then my hunch says the problem is somewhere else in the code. This specific line should work as is. Can you include some code?

Comment: Yes you can find the code on this codepen (included in my first post) : http://codepen.io/Hugo8705/pen/MagpQb

Answer (score 0):

For the refresh icon, change the rotation from `R180` to `R-180` and `R360` to `R0`. This seems to work consistently.

```
clicRefresh = function() {
    fleche.stop().animate({transform: 'S.6,.6 R-180 114.75 122.5'}, 400, mina.easeout, function() {
            fleche.stop().animate({transform: 'S1,1 R0 114.75 122.5'}, 600, mina.easeout);
        });
};
```